# RecipesBase: How to create a recipe for two arrays of structs

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I have two different arrays of structs that I'd like to build a recipe for: `typeof(nodes) == Array{Node{TF}, 1}` and `typeof(elements) == Array{Element{TF}, 1}` (where `TF` is commonly a `Float64`). I'd love to be able to do something like `plot(nodes, elements)` and get back a plot object without adding `Plots` to my package, I'd prefer the lighter weight `RecipesBase`.

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.juliaplots.org/stable/RecipesBase/syntax/), the [overview](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/recipes/), and this [discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/understanding-recipes-in-plots-jl/1912) on using `RecipesBase`.

I was able to get a user recipe working by creating a placeholder struct `NodeMesh` that simply holds the arrays `nodes` and `elements`. The function signature of the recipe looks like: `@recipe function plot_mesh(nodemesh::NodeMesh)`. (And then I promptly unpack the struct inside of the recipe.)

This approach seems ...wrong? I mean it works, but I also could just define a function that returns a dictionary that I pass to Plots. It seems like the series recipe is the correct solution, but I can't get it to work. I've tried a couple of different variations of the function signature (all of which didn't work):

```
@recipe function f(::Type{Val{:gxmesh}}, nodes, elements)
@recipe function plot_mesh(nodes::Vector{Node}, elements::Vector{MeshElement}) 
@recipe function plot_mesh(nodes::Array{Node}, elements::Array{MeshElement})
```

What's the correct approach here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [potential answer in the issues](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1085) of `RecipeBase`.

Here's how I changed the function signature that worked:

```
@recipe function plot_mesh_recipe(nodes::Array{T1, 1}, elements::Array{T2, 1}) where {T1<:Node, T2<:MeshElement}
```

That function returns the x and y of the things I want to plot.